# cxf-xjc-plugin maven error "cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "src\main\java""

Tags: maven, jaxb, cxf, xjc, cxf-xjc-plugin

I am trying to build my maven project which creates POJOs from .xds schema files. I am using cxf-xjc-plugin for xjc execution using below plugin definition.

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsd>src/main/resources</xsd>
                                <packagename>com.myapp.myXmlPojo</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>                    
        </plugin>
```

It fails with below error even when 'src/main/java' directory exists:

[DEBUG] Exception in thread "main" **com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException: cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "src/main/java"**
[DEBUG]         at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument(Options.java:524)
[DEBUG]         at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:827)
[DEBUG]         at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.run(XSDToJavaRunner.java:170)
[DEBUG]         at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.main(XSDToJavaRunner.java:360)

I tried deleting src folder and observed it recreates src/main/java but does not copy the POJOs and fails with above mentioned error.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't like you using `src/main/java` as the location for writing generated java classes since that's the default location for non generated classes.  Try changing this value to something under the target folder, like `${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java`